# Passing messages between the main script and its worker in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, multithreading, web-worker

As I understand a HTML5 Worker and its calling script are "symmetric": both pass asynchronous messages to the other which form synchronous queues. Right, they are symmetric?

Please explain how passing messages from both the main script to the worker and from the worker to the main script work.

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Comment: @SLaks I did. But it is yet unclear to me whether passing messages is symmetric. I may read more